# Is there a way to change value in memory other than by direct access?

Tags: c++, c, linux

```
char *data // Points to some memory having 001E 038CD 0923 8723
```

My intention is to change the value `03` to `02` in memory but don’t want to do anything on data pointer.

I consider copying the data to another variable(`data1`) and editing it.

Is there any way to change the value other than directly changing the value by incrementing the pointer?

```
*(data1+ PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION)  =  SOmeValue;
```

Comment: `*(data+ PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION)` leaves `data` unchanged. `data` pointer is not incremented.

Comment: What is wrong with `data[3]=2`? We’re happy trying to solve problems, but I fail to see the problem here, could you elaborate?

Comment: How else would you change a value? The only thing I can think of is using array-indexing (`data1[PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION] = SomeValue`) but it's exactly the same as the pointer dereference, just a different syntax.

Comment: There's a way, but you'll need some very small pliers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're already doing it correctly:

```
*(data1 + PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION) = SomeValue;
```

or:

```
data1[PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION] = SomeValue;
```

or:

```
PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION[data1] = SomeValue;  // trollolol
```

These are equivalent, and none of them change the value of `data1` itself.

That would only occur if you did this:

```
data1 += PARAMETER_COUNT_POSITION;
*data1 = SomeValue;
```